# Can not use access token in post request for youtube api v3 on AngularJs hybrid app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, youtube, youtube-api

I am making an application that can help me submit the comment from app to video by youtube api v3. Now i have the access token after verified my account with gapi, but i do not know why i can not use the access token with post api althought i have tried with get and it is working good. This is my code i used to send request to youtube api to post my comment:

```
  $scope.commentVideo = function () {
        $http.post('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads', {
            params: {
                part: 'id,snippet',
                snippet: {
                    'channelId': $rootScope.ChanelId,
                    'topLevelComment': {
                        'snippet': {
                            'textOriginal': $scope.cmtstring
                        }
                    },
                    'videoId': $scope.videoId
                },
                access_token: VideosService.getGoogleToken(), //i have get the token from gapi getToken function
                withCredentials: true
            }
        })
          .success(function (data) {
              $log.info(data);

          })
          .error(function (data) {
              $log.info(data);
          });
    };
```

Can you help me?,
Thanks.

Comment: Where's the error information? You left out a lots of details here.

Comment: @charlietfl thank you for your kind. I have found the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the problem, if anyone have this problem like me (or a newbie like me) you just need to use Gapi.client.request to send the post/get request, clear and clean. This is the code i used to send test data:

```
 gapi.client.request({
            path: '/youtube/v3/commentThreads',
            method: 'POST',
            params: { part: 'id,snippet' },
            body: {
                snippet: {
                                'channelId': $rootScope.ChanelId,
                                'topLevelComment': {
                                    'snippet': {
                                        'textOriginal': $scope.cmtstring
                                    }
                                },
                                'videoId': $scope.videoId
                            }
            },
            callback: function (response) {
                $log.info(response);
            }
        });
```

More information about methods and classes of Gapi, read here:

```
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiclientrequestargs
```